# Why would there be some open set which would contain $A$ AND be a member of $T\text{\\}K$?

Tags: general-topology

I am stuck understanding a proof of a lemma.

Here's the lemma: The closure of $A$, $\overline{A}$, is the set

$$\overline{A}:=\{x\in T: U\cap A\neq \emptyset \text{for every open set U that contains x}=\{x\in T: \text{ every (open) neighbourhood of x intersects A}\}$$
Proof:

Suppose that $x\in\overline{A}$. If there is an open set $U$ such taht $x\in U$ and $U\cap A = \emptyset$, then $A\subset T\text{\\}U$. It would follow that $\overline{A}\subset T\text{\\}U$, but that is impossible as $x\in \overline{A}\cap U$ and so $\overline{A}\cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Suppose that $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every open set that contains $x$, but $x\notin \overline{A}$. then $x\notin K$ for some closed set that contains $A$. So $x\in T\text{\\}K$, which is open:

**And here is the part I don't understand**

> in particular there exists an open set $U$ that contains $A$
> that is a subset of $T\text{\\}K$, i.e. that is disjoint from $K$. But $K$ contains $A$, so $U\cap A=\emptyset$, a contradiction.

Why would there be some open set which would contain $A$ AND be a member of $T\text{\\}K$?

Comment: It should be "in particular there exists an open set $U$ that contains $\color{red}x$ ...".

Comment: What is $K$? What is your definition of the closure of $A$, note that $:=$ usually stands for the definition, so your lemma is in fact a definition. I probably know what you mean, but get your stuff right, we are not going to guess things. And above all it makes you confused.

Comment: $U$ is defined as the complement of $K$ and fulfills the requirement, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x \notin \overline{A} = \bigcap \{K\mid K \text{ closed }, A \subseteq K\}$, so it follows there exists *some* closed $K$ with $A \subseteq K$ such that $x \notin K$, this is what your proof also says. It follows from the definition of $\overline{A}$ as that intersection.

Then **define** $U=X\setminus K$. Then $U$ is open as $K$ is closed (!) and $x \in U$ because $x \notin K$. And $$ A \cap U \subseteq K \cap U = K \cap (X\setminus K) = \emptyset$$ so $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $A$, which gives the contradiction..

Comment: Okay, so "some open set $U$ which contains $A$" is a typo, right?

Comment: @user no, not really but the reader is supposed to realise that the complement of the $K$ we just introduced is meant to be used as  this $U$. The symbol $U$ is chosen to mirror the use in the alternative definition of $\overline{A}$ I think.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

> in particular there exists an open set $U$ that contains $x$
> that is a subset of $T\text{\\}K$, i.e. that is disjoint from $K$. But $K$ contains $A$, so $U\cap A=\emptyset$, a contradiction. Does it clarify?